# Do voltage multiplier circuits and transformerless power supplies have functional similarity?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, decoupling-capacitor, multiplier, transformerless

I saw diagrams of voltage multipliers like in the picture below.  To my understanding, it seems like they have the same function as transformerless but the use of a voltage multiplier is to increase voltage and the use of transformerless is to decrease voltage, so I wonder if my understanding is correct about the similarity between the two circuits.

[image]

Comment: These multipliers produce DC outputs from AC inputs

Comment: But this is not what I'm questioning, what I would to know is if this circuit has functional similarity with tronsformerless circuit.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is and isn't *transformerless* for this question&answers.

Answer (score 2):

A transformerless power supply usually refers to a circuit that uses capacitors to convert 120 or 240 VAC mains voltage to a lower voltage for a low voltage, low power power supply for digital or analog components such as microcontrollers and op-amps. Capacitors provide a voltage drop without the power dissipation of resistors. Here is a typical circuit from [Wikipedia - Capacitive power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply):

[image: Transformerless power supply]

This is fundamentally different from charge pumps and voltage multipliers in the sense that the capacitors are used to provide an AC voltage drop, rather than a transfer of charge to boost a voltage or provide a negative voltage.

Some other examples:

https://www.homemade-circuits.com/cheap-yet-useful-transformerless-power/

https://www.elprocus.com/what-is-transformerless-power-supply-its-working/

https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/tutorial-high-current-transformerless-power-supply/

Comment: I would also note that voltage multipliers are more-or-less *multipliers* - you get a fixed multiple of the input voltage out, minus a bit for losses and impedance. Capacitive droppers however are purely impedance based - more current, more voltage drop. You will always find them with a shunt regulator attached or the output voltage would rise to supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not really the same.

A *transformerless power supply* uses capacitance to 'drop' the line voltage to a lower value by inserting an impedance in series. It has very poor power factor and load regulation, but otherwise is reasonably efficient for low-power applications with a predictable load (e.g., 'smart home' accessories like Bluetooth-controlled light bulbs.)

A *voltage multiplier* has a different purpose: it takes AC and produces higher-voltage DC, by using steering diodes to 'stack' capacitor voltages on top of each other as the input phase alternates.

[Here's a simulation of a voltage quadrupler.](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAW3CQBYkEBTAWjDACgATENPbhQ7nl4p%203EBwYAzAIYBXADYAXNgGNu%20cIUiDeYLVCix4pE6bOkQTGmGiUEYSNhRgUpbISow47LiiGbtd119FHEpOSVVECCA6MJebHcDL2NzNIsEBGhiBEgUFES8GmIwGgLDbzYAdzjg7RonWMg2ACcQBtC9esbEgW1c%20DYAc3UEpJ5ohFDtZpGY3trJ6ahh9p6kjqXktgAlUdiupvBwNGpkwwROfYWJkQFQiRkFZV9-O51Yh-DnqL9hUT%200SSMyMcHS6UE0Bc9iwWkINEgGDg5BS7BGgJu-mwU22agmh1uohB8Eg4LSljA2GgSIwhFKhEIKGsaGwNAqkHYAHsQMQQPCDAiLHhAtBlqFedg2NykPz6qTecL2WB%20CJjqEkJKgA)

It's possible (and common) to combine transformer AC step-up with capacitor-diode voltage multiplication to produce even higher DC voltages, yielding higher power and better efficiency than is possible with the multiplier alone.

A related capacitor-based circuit, the *charge pump*, converts DC into higher-voltage and/or opposite polarity DC. Charge pumps use switches to actively transfer capacitor charge between input to output; earning them the name 'flying capacitor' converters. You'll typically find them for low-current analog supplies generated from a digital supply voltage (e.g., take +5V and make +/-5V or +/-10V).

Could you make a step-down regulator with a charge pump approach? Yes, it's possible, however normal practice is to use a buck or flyback convertor as these are very efficient, and for line-powered supplies, provide input-to-output isolation when a transformer is used.

Nevertheless, a while back I played with this transformerless step-down idea. Check it out: [How can I use an AC capacitance voltage divider through diodes to charge a DC capacitor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552433/using-a-ac-capacitance-voltage-divider-through-diodes-to-charge-a-dc-capacitor/552545#552545)

That shows a couple of approaches: a diode-steered step-down, and an actively switched 'flying cap' step-down.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the pros and cons versus a buck / boost converter which uses a switched inductor.

In a multiplier, you lose one diode forward voltage (typically around a volt) per stage, and power is only added to the system when the input voltage is greater than the capacitor voltage of one stage. This is similar to a bridge rectifier, the more current you draw the more the voltage will sag or ripple. These are generally not suitable for large amounts of current, but they are very useful when a small amount of current is needed at a higher voltage. One very common application is to generate high voltage for erasing flash memory without requiring the board designer to provide it on a separate pin; it can be generated from 3.3 or 5 volts.

In a boost converter, the limits on efficiency are the inductor resistance and switching efficiency. Saturation current also limits the maximum power for a given size inductor. The greater the voltage multiplication the less current will be available, but at a high switching frequency (tens to hundreds of kHz) you can get very stable voltage at high current.

You may also find it useful to know that multipliers are sometimes referred to as charge pumps.

Comment: The question was about transformerless power supplies and voltage multipliers.  There was nothing in it about boost converters.

Answer (score 0):

> To my understanding, it seems like they have the same function as transformerless but the use of a voltage multiplier is to increase voltage and the use of transformerless is to decrease voltage, so I wonder if my understanding is correct about the similarity between the two circuits.

My answer is: Yes, if by "transformless" you mean the so-called "capacitive dropper" below.

## Basic idea

The most general idea is to use the  storage properties of capacitors.

### Capacitor as a "rechargeable battery"

Such circuits are intuitively best understood if we think of the capacitor as a kind of "rechargeable battery" (something well known to us from everyday life). Of course, this is a very rough analogy because a capacitor is much like a flexible "battery" (it can be charged/discharged very quickly over a wide voltage range). Imagine that it is initially discharged and its voltage is 0 V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xnpv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### Copying voltage

If we connect it in parallel to a voltage source, it will be quickly charged to its voltage. So we now have two voltage sources - *original* and *clone*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcCDQt.png)</sup>

If we now connect them in series, their voltages will be added or subtracted depending on the polarity of the connection.

### Multiplying voltage

If the sources are oriented in the same direction, their voltages will be summed and the total voltage will be twice the output voltage (the voltage will be multiplied by two or *doubled*).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSDt8T.png)</sup>

### Dropping voltage

If the sources are oriented in opposite directions, their voltages will be subtracted and the total voltage will be less than the initial voltage (the voltage will be reduced, dropped).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3tYbo.png)</sup>

## Voltage multiplier

If we connect two or more capacitors  through diode switches to the mains, their voltages will be summed. I have considered such a voltage doubler circuit in another [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/483061/61398). Here I will consider the capacitive dropping circuit.

## Capacitive AC dropper

So, if we connect a capacitor in series to an AC voltage source (e.g., the US 120 V mains), it will continuously charge and discharge.

### Reactance demystified

Its voltage, shifted by some value, will follow the input voltage, subtracting from it and thus reducing it. This behavior of the capacitor is known as "reactance". As you can see, there is nothing mystical about this phenomenon.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe7Vpo.png)</sup>

***Note:** I have made an inaccuracy. The voltage here should be 170 V (peak value) and not 120 V (RMS value). For the purposes of this intuitive explanation, it does not really matter, but if it bothers you, I will correct it.*

### Typical points

To explain the circuit in the simplest possible way, I have chosen five typical points on the graph...

[image: Transformless power supply_5 microF_1]

... and for each of them I have drawn, like a snapshot, the corresponding equivalent circuit with constant voltage sources. To simplify the circuit, I have used a little trick (from the "CircuitLab bag of tricks":) - a voltmeter with a greatly reduced resistance (100 ohm) acts as the load RL. I have set it in the voltmeter *parameters* window.

**Point 1:** Vin is more positive than the zero Vc (bat). So Vin is a (positive) source and the capacitor is a load. The current flows from Vin to Vc; it continuosly decreases but still the "battery" is charging.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4U0k8.png)</sup>

**Point 2:** Both voltages are positive and equal. There is no current flowing; the output voltage across the load is zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fltOmg.png)</sup>

**Point 3:** Like in point 1, Vc is zero but now Vin is more negative than Vc. The current flows from Vc to Vin; it continuosly decreases but still the "battery" is charging. The capacitor returns the stored energy to the mains (a unique property of storing devices like capacitors and inductors).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flwDJa.png)</sup>

**Point 4:** Again, both voltages are equal but negative. There is no current flowing; the output voltage across the load is zero.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2for0Hr.png)</sup>

**Point 5:** Vin is zero; so it is more positive than the negative Vc. The current flows from Vin to Vc; it continuously decreases but still the "battery" is charging.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0AP4F.png)</sup>

## Capacitive AC-DC dropper

As you can see, the load must be bidirectional because the current alternatively reverses its direction. So we put it in a diode bridge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVM4mV.png)</sup>

The output voltage across the load is full-wave rectified.

[image: Transformless power supply_5 microF_2]